# A detail in the proof of a version of the Intermediate Value Theorem (IVT)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am having some trouble understanding a line in a proof of the IVT.

THEOREM (IVT) If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)f(b)<0$, then $f(c)=0$ for some $c$ on $(a,b)$.

PROOF
Since one of $f(a),f(b)$ is negative, we can consider the theorem for $-f$ rather than $f$ and so, without loss of generality, we suppose that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$. By continuity of $f$ on $[a,b]$, if $f(x)<0$, then there is an interval $I_x$ around $x$ such that $f<0$ on $I_x \cap [a,b]$ and similarly at points such as $b$, where $f>0$. In particular, $f(x)<0$ for all $x$ on $[a,X]$, for some $X$ where $a<X<b$. Let $c$ denote the supremum of the set of such $X$.

**It follows that      $f(x)<0$ for all $x$ on $[a,c)$.**

Therefore $f(c)$ cannot be positive, by continuity from the left at $c$.But also $f(c)$ is not negative.

If it were, **then $c \ne b$ and $f(x)<0$ for an interval around $c$.**

Since also $f(x)<0$ on $[a,c)$, it would follow that $f$ is negative on $[a, c']$ for some $c'>c$. This contradicts the definition of $c$, so $f(c)=0$.

I don't understand the isolated lines in bold. Moreover, I don't understand why we end up with $f(x)$ being negative on $[a,c)$ in the first line. For the second line, I think $f(x)$ being negative for an interval around $c$ is due to continuity, but I don't get why the author wrote $c \ne b$.

If someone could help, I would be grateful.

Comment: If $x<c$ then there must be an $X$ which satisfies $x<X\leq c$ such that $f$ is negative on $[a,X):$ by the definition of $c.$

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your comment. I was wondering why we end up with $[a,c)$ in the first line though. I'll edit my question a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c=b$, then $f(c)=f(b)>0$ and, by continuity at $b$, there would be some $\delta>0$ such that (1) $a<c-\delta$ and (2) $f>0$ on $(c-\delta,c]$, which would contradict the definition of $c$ because the definition of supremum requires the existence of some $X$ between $c-\delta$ and $c$. In consequence $c<b$.

The condition $f<0$ in an interval around $c$ is a direct consequence of the continuity of $f$ at $c$.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that Leandro! I am still wondering why I get $f(x)<0$ for all $x$ on $(a,c]$ though.

Comment: Not the proper statement. What you know is that $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in[a,c)$. This is because $c=\sup A$, where $A=\{y\in[a,b]\mid f<0 \text{ on } [a,y]\}$. Keep in mind that, by definition, the supremum is an upper bound that satisfies: for all $\epsilon>0$, exists $y\in A$ with $c-\epsilon < y$.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about getting the interval $[a,c)$ wrong! I suppose I wanted to know why the first bold line wasn't something like $f(x)<0$ for all $x$ on $[a,c].$

Comment: All you know is that $f<0$ on $[a,c)$. In fact the proof shows that $f(c)=0$ and not $<0$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I suppose I was getting confused by the structure of the proof. You see, we first define $c$ to be the supremum of the set $A$ you defined. Then the author writes "it follows that $f<0$ on $[a,c)$" without $c$ being included in the interval. But, as you said, the whole point of the proof is to show that $f(c)$ is neither positive nor negative. Thanks